How do I verify if an element is visible in Appium?
I think I must be doing something fundamentally wrong.  I am using Expo router from the default example and I added a testID
<TabBarIcon
  name={focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline'}
  color={color}
  testID='home-tab-button'
/>

But it can't find if it I do
driver = await buildDriver({
  platformName: 'Android',
  'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
  'appium:deviceName': 'Android',
  'appium:app': '/app-release.apk',
  'appium:autoGrantPermissions': true,
});
const splash = await driver.$('~home-tab-button');
await splash.waitForExist({
  timeout: 30000
});

And it does not appear on Appium Inspector either


Update: I also tried an app-debug.apk version no luck with the IDs in Appium Inspector
Update: Looking at some of the bugs on Appium + react-native + testID.  It sounds like Appium developers push the blame to React Native
